# Custom filters address and date range in dataTables

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I'm trying to filter the dataTable using custom filters are `date range`, `radius` and `location`.

I need to calculate the radius between entered location to each `site` column location from the table which should match with entered radius, then show the results.

`date range` should filter  `dates column` from the table.
`radius` and `postcode` should filter `site column` from the table.

But my function doesn't result anything in return, I'm not getting where's the mistake.

Html code:

```
 <table class="transport-search">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px !important"><input name="min" id="min" type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Min Date"></td>

      <td style="padding: 10px !important"> <input name="max" id="max" type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Max Date"></td>

      <td style="padding: 10px !important"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="radius" placeholder="Radius"></td>

      <td style="padding: 10px !important"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" placeholder="Address/Postcode"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table-striped table table-bordered table-condensed transport">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th width="4%">JobID</th>
      <th width="8%">Customer</th>
      <th width="11%">Site</th>
      <th width="8%">Site Contact</th>
      <th width="8%">Direction</th>
      <th width="8%">Dates</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN52
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1281 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">BDS Yorkshire Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins"> Hilderthorpe Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Bridlington </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> East Yorkshire </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> YO15 3AZ </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Jane Mason </p>
        <p class="no-margins">jaynem@bdsyorkshire.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">01377 240403 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        02/02/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN52
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1281 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">BDS Yorkshire Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins"> Hilderthorpe Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Bridlington </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> East Yorkshire </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> YO15 3AZ </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Jane Mason </p>
        <p class="no-margins">jaynem@bdsyorkshire.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">01377 240403 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        02/02/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN52
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1281 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">BDS Yorkshire Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins"> Hilderthorpe Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Bridlington </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> East Yorkshire </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> YO15 3AZ </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Jane Mason </p>
        <p class="no-margins">jaynem@bdsyorkshire.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">01377 240403 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        02/02/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN52
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1281 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">BDS Yorkshire Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins"> Hilderthorpe Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Bridlington </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> East Yorkshire </p>
        <p class="no-margins"> YO15 3AZ </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Jane Mason </p>
        <p class="no-margins">jaynem@bdsyorkshire.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">01377 240403 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        02/02/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN63</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1249 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Windser Road Surfacing</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Etton Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins">Cherry Burton</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Beverley</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">HU17 7RP</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Gordon Blair</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN63</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1249 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Windser Road Surfacing</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Etton Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins">Cherry Burton</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Beverley</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">HU17 7RP</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Gordon Blair</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        01/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        01/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        01/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        01/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        29/03/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        29/03/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        29/03/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> H56</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1177 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Toppesfield Limited</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Race Track </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Three Sisters Road </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Ashton in Makerfield </p>
        <p class="no-margins">Wigan </p>
        <p class="no-margins">WN4 8DD </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Craig Germeney </p>
        <p class="no-margins">craig.germeney@toppesfield.com </p>
        <p class="no-margins">07773 257824 </p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        29/03/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN62</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1114 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">NMC Surfacing</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Kimberley Caravans</p>
        <p class="no-margins">Burtree Lane</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Darlington</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">DL2 2XZ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Elaine Sheppard</p>
        <p class="no-margins">elaine.sheppard@nmcsurfacing.co.uk</p>
        <p class="no-margins">01302 275131</p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN62</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1114 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">NMC Surfacing</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Kimberley Caravans</p>
        <p class="no-margins">Burtree Lane</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Darlington</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">DL2 2XZ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Elaine Sheppard</p>
        <p class="no-margins">elaine.sheppard@nmcsurfacing.co.uk</p>
        <p class="no-margins">01302 275131</p>
      </td>
      <td>Delivery</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN69</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1094 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">C R MacDonald Ltd</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Hewell Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Redditch</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">B97 6AE</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Michael Siverns </p>
        <p class="no-margins">michael.siverns@crmacdonald.co.uk </p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN69</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1094 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">C R MacDonald Ltd</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Hewell Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Redditch</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">B97 6AE</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Michael Siverns </p>
        <p class="no-margins">michael.siverns@crmacdonald.co.uk </p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN69</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1094 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">C R MacDonald Ltd</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Hewell Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Redditch</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">B97 6AE</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Michael Siverns </p>
        <p class="no-margins">michael.siverns@crmacdonald.co.uk </p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p class="no-margins"> CN69</p>
      </td>
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <p class="no-margins">1094 </p>
        <p class="no-margins">C R MacDonald Ltd</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Hewell Road</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">Redditch</p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
        <p class="no-margins">B97 6AE</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="no-margins">Michael Siverns </p>
        <p class="no-margins">michael.siverns@crmacdonald.co.uk </p>
        <p class="no-margins"></p>
      </td>
      <td>Collection</td>
      <td>
        27/04/2018
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input.date').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    autoclose: true
  });

  var table = $('.transport').DataTable();


  $("#min").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table.draw();
    }
  });

  $("#max").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table.draw();
    }
  });

  $('#min, #max').on('keyup', function() {

    table.draw();

  });

  $('#postcode, #radius').on('keyup', function() {

    table.draw();
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {

    // min and max dates matching
    var dateStart = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
    var dateEnd = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
    var evalDate = new Date(data[5]);

    if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

    var source = $("#postcode").val();
    var radius = $("#radius").val();

    table.columns().eq(2).each(function(index) {
      var column = table.column(index);

      var destination = column.data();

      distanceCalc(source, destination).then(calcs => {

        if (radius == calcs) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      }).catch(err => {
        return false;
      })

    });



  });

});

function distanceCalc(source, destination) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var values = [];
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
    var request = {
      origin: source,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        // directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
    //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [source],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;

        if (distance) {
          resolve(distance);
        } else {
          reject("Lat&Long required as address does not validate");
        }
      } else {
        reject("Lat&Long required as address does not validate");
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Link for [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/harshitha_naidu/9ymtosp7/)

Comment: It is a little bit confusing. What datepicker are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap date picker. Please let me know whats confusing you? I'll explain you a bit clear.

Comment: Ah - no, you are using jQueryUI datePicker.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying generate the datePickers twice. Seems to me you first initialise with a certain set of defaults, then try to reinitialise in order to add a `onSelect` handler. Use `setDefaults` instead, i.e

```js
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  autoclose: true
});
```

Now the datePicker is actually iinitialised upon

```js
$("#min").datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

and `table.draw()` is executed when a new date is selected.

---

The next problem is that you are parsing illegal dates. You are trying to `Date()` on a european `dd/mm/yyyy` notation. You must convert to `mm/dd/yyyy` in order to get it to work. Besides that, your date evaluation does not take `null` dates into consideration - you accidently exclude all rows if either `#min` or `#max` not is set. Change your code to

```js
var d = data[5].split('/');
var evalDate = new Date(d[1]+'/'+d[0]+'/'+d[2]);
```

and

```js
var dateStart = $('#min').datepicker("getDate") || new Date();
var dateEnd = $('#max').datepicker("getDate") || new Date();
```

new forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/r84wfyud/**

Comment: Ah got it, But even then its not filtering the data :(

Comment: Oh yes it is filtered, you just have some common mistakes in your evaluation.  See update. I dont want to go into your `distanceCalc()` just remember that when you `return` from a function you actually return out of that function, the `distanceCalc` code will most probably never be executed. You must combine the `distanceCalc` and the date evaluation all together.

Comment: Yes, now the dates are filtering fine. :) Thank you so much for the help. Yes, I got your point about `distanceCalc()` , I'll make them combined. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @06011991, you are welcome! Thank you for accepting the answer. Hope you easily can integrate distanceCalc() into the evaluation. Perhaps first checking for date range, then perform distanceCalc on positives only. I would build up a cache of already found distanceCalc return values to prevent the same calls over and over. You could also start building up the results for distanceCalc in the background, as soon the page is loaded.

Comment: I'm trying to perform `distanceCalc`, but its failing. Trying with OR operation.